# mIRC/mSL words from readini, can they be split?

Tags: scripting, mirc

Brand new to mSL and just playing around with trying to make a bot. 
So I am trying to make something that when a user says a certain word, they get +1 to a count against their name. However they can then not say the word again to further increase their count unlimited times, they must find a new word.

To ensure the words cannot be used multiple times I am writing the words to a file, I then need to load these words and check if its been said already or not against what the user has just said, and act appropriately

```
on *:TEXT:&:#:{
var %msg

if ($1 == text1) { %msg = msg1 }
elseif ($1 == text2) { %msg = msg2 }
elseif ($1 == text3) { %msg = msg3 }
else { return }
msg # %msg 

var %keyword = $readini(keyword.ini,#,$nick)
if (%keyword == $1) {
 msg # you already have this keyword! :(
}
else {
  var %count = $readini(cookies.ini,#,$nick)
  inc %count
  writeini cookies.ini # $nick %count
  writeini keyword.ini # $nick %keyword $+ , $+ $1
 }
}
```

keyword.ini file looks like:

```
nickname=text1,text2
```

is there anyway in mSL that I can grab the list (already done in code above) and then use something similar to .split(,) to divide up the words to run through a for/next?

Thanks in advance

**EDIT:** 
I tried out the below and although it did work! I then deleted the file to test it out, and it never remade the file despite the writeini. I even added a writeini keyword.ini at the start of the script to make sure the file is present before any text is written, still didn't make it.

```
on *:TEXT:&:#:{
  var %msg

if ($1 == text1) { %msg = msg1 }
elseif ($1 == text2) { %msg = msg2 }
elseif ($1 == text3) { %msg = msg3 }
else { return }
msg # %msg 

  var %i = 1, %keyword = $readini(keyword.ini,n,$chan,$nick), %cookie = $readini(cookies.ini,n,#,$nick)
  while (%i <= $numtok(%keyword, 44)) {
    if ($istok(%keyword, $1, 44)) {
      msg # you already have this keyword! :(
    }
    else {
      inc %cookie
      writeini cookies.ini $chan $nick %cookie
      msg # congrats! you found a keywords
      writeini keyword.ini $chan $nick $addtok(%keyword, $1, 44)
    }
    inc %i
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for mIRC's token identifiers. I would suggest reading the help files (/help token identifiers) to read more about them.

Use `$istok()` to check whether the line contains that keyword already:

```
if ($istok(%keyword, $1, 44)) // Keyword exists
```

Use `$addtok()` to add a new keyword to the line, and then write it to the file:

```
writeini keyword.ini # $nick $addtok(%keyword, $1, 44)
```

Use `$numtok()` and `$gettok()` to create a loop to read all the values:

```
var %i = 1, %keywords = $readini(cookies.ini, n, channel, nick)
while (%i <= $numtok(%keywords, 44)) {
  echo -a Keyword %i $+ : $gettok(%keywords, %i, 44)
  inc %i
}
```

**Important note**: **always** use the `n` switch with `$readini()` (like I did above) when reading data, *especially* when it's data that users can enter. Without it, `$readini()` will evaluate the contents (e.g., $me will be evaluated to your current nickname). Users can inject malicious code this way.

---

**Edit for the inserted question:** You are using a while loop to check whether they possess the cookie - it will loop once for every cookie they have (0 loops for no cookies). You don't need this while loop at all, since `$istok(%keywords $1, 44)` will take *all* the keywords and return `$true` if `$1` is in that list of tokens.

Just the following will suffice:

```
var %keywords = $readini(keyword.ini,n,$chan,$nick), %cookie = $readini(cookies.ini,n,#,$nick)
if ($istok(%keywords, $1, 44)) {
  ; the token $1 is in the list of tokens %keywords
  msg # you already have this cookie! :(
}
else {
  ; the token $1 did not appear in the list of tokens %keywords
  inc %cookie
  writeini cookies.ini $chan $nick %cookie
  writeini keyword.ini $chan $nick $addtok(%keywords, $1, 44)
}
```

Comment: many thanks for your reply seeing as it's the only one, i'll try this when I can and get back to you.

Comment: tried out the code, and it worked, thanks; but then i deleted the file and it stopped working. is there a way to check the file is there fire, i have read it's something like $isfile but i couldn't get it to work. edited the main question with updated code

Comment: @directpixel I have updated my reply to answer your additional question.

Comment: i see, i understand now and how tokens work after reading your posts and wiki, many thanks.

Comment: Hi Patrick, I've posted nother mirc question, which so far, has no answers, do you think you could take a quick look if you get the time please.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22404264/get-highest-value-from-a-file-using-msl-and-mirc

Comment: Hi directpixel, I've answered your question for you.