# Get highest value from a file using mSL and mIRC

Tags: loops, scripting, irc, mirc

Currently I have an irc bot that when a user says a keyword e.g test1 they get +1 added to their count, which is stored in a file. However I wanted to know who had the biggest count (who was winning). I thought something like a while loop would work, looking for the numbers against the nickname, unfortunately, although my pseudo code is correct, the theoretical code, not so much.

This is what I have so far.

```
on *:TEXT:!winning:#:{
  var %i = 1, %highest = 0, %mycookie = $readini(cookies.ini,n,#,$nick)

  while (%i < $lines(cookies.ini)) {
    if (%mycookie > %highest) {
      %highest = %mycookie
          if (%highest == 1) {
      msg $chan $nick is winning with %highest count. }
      elseif (%highest > 1) {
      msg $chan $nick is winning with %highest counts. }
      else {
            msg $chan No one has any count! Must try harder! }
    }
        else { return }  
    inc %i
  }
}
```

I'm looking to cycle through the file and whenever it finds a higher number than %highest (which starts at 0) put this into the variable, and move to the next name.
Similarly, I'm aware that using $nick is wrong as that will display MY nickname, instead of grabbing the nickname from the file... can I grab the nickname from the file?

Thanks

Similarly, on a completely unrelated note. Is there a way in mIRC to use a different script file per channel? 
Something like:

```
if ($chan == #mychan) {
  $remote == script1.ini }
else { }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can loop through the contents of an INI file using the `$ini()` identifier. `$ini(cookies.ini, $chan, 0)` will return the total of people with a record on that channel, whereas `$ini(cookies.ini, $chan, N)` will return the name of the Nth person (which can then be passed as the last parameter in `$readini()`).

Furthermore, don't include the messages with the if/elseif/else structure inside the while loop; you'll probably want to message the outcome once, after the highest record has been found:

```
on *:TEXT:!winning:#:{
  var %i = 1, %highestCookies = 0, %highestUser

  ; This will run as long as %i is smaller than or equal to the number of lines in the ini section $chan
  while (%i <= $ini(cookies.ini, $chan, 0)) {

    ; As we loop through the file, store the item name (the nickname) and the cookies (the value) 
    var %user = $ini(cookies.ini, $chan, %i), %cookies = $readini(cookies.ini, n, $chan, %user)

    ; Is this the highest found so far?
    if (%cookies > %highestCookies) {
      var %highestCookies = %cookies
      var %highestUser = %user
    }

    inc %i
  }

  ; Now that we have the correct values in our variables, display the message once
  if (%highestCookies == 1) {
    msg $chan %highestUser is winning with %highestCookies count.
  }
  elseif (%highestCookies > 1) {
    msg $chan %highestUser is winning with %highestCookies counts.
  }
  else {
    msg $chan No one has any count! Must try harder!
  }
}
```

**Edit:** Fixed an issue that caused no higher values to be found because %highestCookies was assigned a $null value instead of 0.

---

As for your second question, it's not possible to have different script files for different channels. However, you could modify the **location** parameter in the event catchers so it only catchers events on specific channels. As an example, this is how an `on TEXT` would look like:

```
; This event will only listen to the word "hello" in #directpixel and #stackoverflow
on *:TEXT:hello:#directpixel,#stackoverflow:{
  msg $chan Hello $nick $+ !
}
```

Comment: awesome, again thank you very much. seems like you're the lead guy on Stack Overflow when it comes to mSL!

Comment: I'm glad I could help! It's not a very busy topic on SO these days, but I'm subscribed to mIRC related questions and will attempt to answer your future questions.

Comment: hi patrick, finally got around to trying the code above, and it doesn't seem to pick up the values from the cookies.ini file, and the outcome is always "msg $chan No one has any count! Must try harder!" even when cookies to exist and smeone is the highest.

Comment: i have added in various msg $chan ### for debugging and they are never written to channel, seems like the while doesn't even run.

Comment: That's odd. Try debugging by using a command like `//echo -a $ini(cookies.ini, #channel, 0)` to see if it returns a number bigger than 0 (this should return the number of records for that channel). If this returns 0, it will never run the while loop.

Comment: Is there any IRC server/channel I can visit to help you more easily some time?

Comment: I am making the bot for a Twitch channel (live streaming of games), I know they use a minimised version of irc, e.g don't allow whispering, perhaps they dont allow $ini either? altho $readini and $writeini work fine. Twitch name is the same as here on SO.
I tried the debugging command you provided above, and this didn't print out anything except the final else command also:
else {
    msg $chan No one has any count! Must try harder!
  }